# programa con condicionales en python if elif else no se ejecuta como deseo

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones

Estoy creando una función que consiste en que el programe le pregunta al usuario si es mayor de edad o no para así poder dejarlo acceder al website, este es mi código:

```
def edad_limite():
    '''
    El programa pregunta al usuario si es mayor de edad o no para dejarlo ingresar
    al website, dependiendo de su respuesta arrojar alguno de estos mensajes:
    si= puede acceder
    no= tienes un permiso de tus padres?
        si= haz click aquí para enviarlo
        no= 'Lo siento, necesitas un permiso o ser mayor de edad'
    '''
    pregunta= "Eres mayor de edad?"
    respuesta= input(pregunta)


    if (respuesta== 'si' or respuesta= 'sí'):
        return 'puedes acceder'

    elif respuesta == 'no':
        pregunta_permiso= "tienes un permiso?"
        respuesta_permiso= input(pregunta_permiso)
        if (respuesta_permiso == 'si' or respuesta_permiso == 'sí'):
            return 'haz click aqui para enviar el permiso'
        else:
            return 'Lo siento, necesitas un permiso o ser mayor de edad'
```

El problema radica en que cuando contesto 'si' a la pregunta de "Eres mayor de edad" se siguen ejecutando los otros condicionales y sus respectivos bloques y tampoco retorna el mensaje de "puedes acceder". Tengo entendido que esto pasa cuando una condición no se cumple, pero no entiendo la razón aquí en mi código. Ayudaa:(

Comment: Falta un segundo `=` en el `or` del primer `if`

Answer (score 1):

En tu primera linea en lugar de:

```
if (respuesta == 'si' or respuesta= 'sí'):
```

Prueba con:

```
if (respuesta == 'si' or respuesta == 'sí'):
```

Nota que el operador `=` es de asignación y el operador `==` es de comparación

Como extra puedes considerar convertir tu respuesta a minúscula, de la siguiente manera: (no importará si escribes SI, Si, sI, Sí ...)

```py
if (respuesta.lower() == 'si' or respuesta.lower() == 'sí'):
```